# Smart can't install...no package provides shared object file

Tags: java, rpm, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

## Problem

I'm attempting to create a Bitbake recipe which will install Oracle JRE 8 onto my target OS.

I've tried to use metadata from [meta-oracle-java](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-oracle-java), but had some difficulties due to one of the `.inc` files which are provided for general JREs has a JRE-7-specific URI.

I've changed some of the metadata from meta-oracle-java and created my own recipe to do this install.

## Tests

#### A Build of the JRE Recipe by Itself

When building the recipe by itself:

```
bitbake oracle-jse-jre
```

The build completes without error. I've added a dependency on `libav` into the `oracle-jse-jre` recipe, so I can do the following from `TMPDIR`:

```
$ find . -name libavformat*so 
./work/core2-64-poky-linux/libav/9.18-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/lib/libavformat.so.54.20.4
./work/core2-64-poky-linux/libav/9.18-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/lib/libavformat.so
./work/core2-64-poky-linux/libav/9.18-r0/sysroot-destdir/usr/lib/libavformat.so.54
./sysroots/genericx86-64/usr/lib/libavformat.so.54.20.4
./sysroots/genericx86-64/usr/lib/libavformat.so
./sysroots/genericx86-64/usr/lib/libavformat.so.54
```

#### Runtime Dependency Success

If I add the default package from the `oracle-jse-jre` recipe to `RDEPENDS_${PN}` of another recipe `xenoros_0.1.bb`, I can run `bitbake xenoros` and build without errors.

#### Core Image Failure

If I add `xenoros` to the `IMAGE_INSTALL` variable of a `core-image-xenoros`, the build fails with the following error:

```
ERROR: Unable to install packages. Command '/home/presslertj/yocto-OS/poky-jethro-build/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/smart --log-level=warning --data-dir=/home/presslertj/yocto-OS/poky-jethro-build/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/core-image-my-server/1.0-r0/rootfs/var/lib/smart install -y message-generation@core2_64 catkin@core2_64 python-distutils@core2_64 ldd@core2_64 xenoros@core2_64 rosgraph@core2_64 gedit@core2_64 actionlib@core2_64 python-compression@core2_64 dhcp-server@core2_64 libpthread-stubs@core2_64 tf2@core2_64 python-email@core2_64 catkin-dev@core2_64 git@core2_64 rosbash@core2_64 python-json@core2_64 python-wstool@core2_64 connman@core2_64 ros-config@core2_64 packagegroup-core-boot@genericx86_64 libsdl-1.2-0@core2_64 rosjava@core2_64 quagga@core2_64 nginx@core2_64 rospy@core2_64 apt@core2_64 libc6@core2_64 netcat@core2_64 shadow@core2_64 bash@core2_64 roscpp@core2_64 roslaunch@core2_64 run-postinsts@all python-rosinstall@core2_64 elfutils@core2_64 openssl@core2_64 font-alias@all gradle@core2_64 python-catkin-pkg@core2_64 catkin-runtime@core2_64 catkin-runtime-dev@core2_64 pciutils@core2_64 base-passwd@core2_64' returned 1:
Loading cache...
Updating cache...               ######################################## [100%]

Computing transaction...error: Can't install oracle-jse-jre-1.8.0-u77r0@core2_64: no package provides libavformat.so.53(LIBAVFORMAT_53)(64bit)

ERROR: Function failed: do_rootfs
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/presslertj/yocto-OS/poky-jethro-build/build/tmip/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/core-image-my-server/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.22073
ERROR: Task 7 (/home/presslertj/yocto-OS/poky-jethro-build/meta-myLayer/recipes-core/images/core-image-my-server.bb, do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'
```

Looking inside `TMPDIR`, I can find this:

```
/sysroots/genericx86-64/usr/lib/libavformat.so.54
```

It seems there's a version mismatch, where smart expects version 53, but 54 is provided.

#### Reverting `libav`'s version

Just to test what's going on, I've made a recipe which fetches version `0.8.17` of `libav` (which uses version 53).  When using this instead of `9.18`, I have the exact opposite problem, that smart expects but can't find version 54.

## Questions

1. How does smart determine the version number for these shared object files?
2. What about the do_rootfs() task causes the build to fail at this specific time?
3. Is there a simple resolution to my specific problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It's not smart, but rather rpmbuild, that is adding dependencies derived from the ELF `DT_NEEDED` field (see `elfutils -a`).

2) The `do_rootfs()` task is failing because of unresolved dependencies.

3) Since you are using Poky/Yocto and rpm5, there is a simple way to mask the issue (substituting whatever dependencies are causing you heartburn)

```
echo "unresoved_dependency" > /etc/rpm/sysinfo/Providename
```

That is just a band-aid; you still need to figure out the packaging issues rather than masking the underlying problem with how you are building rpm packages.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that still encounter this error: as stated in the README file of the meta-oracle-java repo

```
There are some known install problems for JRE packages due to dependencies reported by RPM package manager. 
Switching to DEB or IPK packaging temporarily fixes this. 
ie: 
PACKAGE_CLASSES = "package_deb"  
or   
PACKAGE_CLASSES = "package_ipk"
in your 'local.conf' file
```