# "No package provides libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_219)" during do_rootfs

Tags: yocto, rpm, systemd, bitbake, openembedded

I'm attempting to build an image with the phytec bsp 18.2 from here: https://wiki.phytec.com/productinfo/phycore-i-mx7/bsp-yocto-fsl-imx7/

I require a newer version of systemd (> 234) and so am substituting the systemd recipe for version 234 from rocko, found here: http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-core/systemd?h=rocko by putting this in a custom layer.  However, during the do_rootfs step, I receive an error that "No package provides libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_219).  I've tried a work-around recommended here: [Smart can't install...no package provides shared object file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703804/smart-cant-install-no-package-provides-shared-object-file) and it didn't solve the issue.  I've tried echoing `libsystemd.so.0`, `LIBSYSTEMD_219`, and `libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_219)` to both `${rootfs}/etc/rpm/sysinfo/Providename` and `${rootfs}/var/lib/rpm/Providename` and had no luck.  Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?  I'd appreciate any help that could be offered, and please let me know if I can offer any more information.

Comment: Did you check their git repos https://git.phytec.de/meta-phytec/ for a newer release?

Comment: I just ran `repo sync` to pull the latest versions of everything and re-built.  Same issue.  The issue is with installing python3-systemd-234, if that helps.

Comment: Have you looked at which package/binary wants libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_219) and why?

Comment: @JussiKukkonen I don't get any results from running `rg LIBSYSTEMD_219` and `rg libsystemd.so.0` on my sources directory.

Comment: This could easily happen with e.g. a binary that's not built by Yocto getting installed on the rootfs. I would expect you to find the context in the build log: you could include more than the one error line in your question

Comment: @JussiKukkonen Here's the full log: http://ix.io/2qJV  I don't seen anything that appears to cause this, but maybe you do?

Comment: suprisingly terse log yes :) but it does tell you where you can look: python3-systemd. for some reason it seems to contain binaries linked with systemd 219. Find the recipe $WORKDIR and check the build logs and maybe check the built binaries yourself with (I think) `objdump -p path/to/library.so | grep NEEDED`

Comment: I now notice the recipe name is already mentioned in a comment: sorry about that. Advice still stands

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the yocto wrapper, etc, but in standard RPM-land, this error:

> `Computing transaction...error: Can't install python3-systemd-234-r0.0@cortexa7hf_neon: no package provides libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_219)`

means that there is a `.so` or executable in the RPM named `python3-systemd-234-r0.0` that was compiled with a specific version of `libsystemd.so.0` that had the flag `LIBSYSTEMD_219`. That flag is the "ELF Symbol Versioning" and it's seen most with `GLIBC_XX` when you try to install an RPM that's too new for a target system (*e.g.* CentOS 7 RPM on CentOS 6).

The `systemd` on your target machine is too old, so it only defines the versions it is compatible with, *e.g.* `libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_210)` or similar.

What you need to do is build your `python3-systemd-234-r0.0` on a machine with the same version of `systemd` as the target (or cross-compile appropriately), or create a `systemd` RPM that includes the functionality you're attempting.

So you need to figure out how to apply one of these solutions to your build system; sorry I don't know enough about yocto to help there.